# Jhipster4: what are the benefits of using DTO

Tags: java, jhipster, dto

Jhipster4 adds Data Transfer Objects (DTO) just what is the benefit of using DTO objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main benefit is to control more precisely which properties you expose from your entities and also to expose entity aggregates rather than single entities.

Answer (score 1):

DTO, stands for Data Transfer Object, is a design pattern conceived to reduce the number of calls when working with remote interfaces.

The advantage of using DTOs, is that they can help hiding implementation details of domain objects (aka. entities). Exposing entities through endpoints can become a security issue if we do not carefully handle what properties can be changed through what operations.

For context, here is an example endpoint using DTOs in Java (Spring Boot):

```
public class ProductDTO {
    private String name;
    private Double price;
}

public class Product {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Double price;
}

@PostMapping("/products")
public ResponseEntity<ProductDTO> createProduct(
    @RequestBody Product request
) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go Through this link about DTO.
[Data Transfer Object](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

- An object that carries data between processes in order to reduce the number of method calls.

The main reason for using a Data Transfer Object is to **batch up what would be multiple remote calls into a single call,** it's worth mentioning that another advantage is to encapsulate the serialization mechanism for transferring data over the wire. By encapsulating the serialization like this, the DTOs keep this logic out of the rest of the code and also provide a clear point to change serialization should you wish.